# treat a jar as a zip

Tags: java, jar, zip

I want to read files form my *jar archive. I read in the internet how to read from zip:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile( "moers.zip" );
ZipEntry entry  = zipFile.getEntry( "DerAlteSack.png" );
InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream( entry );
```

So my question: Can I treat a *jar file as a *zip file?

Comment: Yes a jar file is a zip file.

Comment: You should use the class loader to get resources.

Comment: Yup, in fact [`JarFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) extends `ZipFile`.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: Sorry but in my opininon it isn't

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Intro
At the binary level it's exactly a zip file. This isn't philosophy, opinions have little room here.  A JarFile just happens to contain a special directory structure with a manifest (META-INF) with a bit of meta information.  As far as treatment of a jar in Java is concerned there are special classes for it either using JarFile or using class.getResource* methods. But your question about reading a jar file and whether it can be treated as a zip file; which points to the structure of .jar which is identical to a .zip

Comment: @AhmedMasud: I mean: it isn't a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes a jar IS a Zip file. See the specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Intro

> A  JAR file is essentially a zip file that contains an optional
>   META-INF directory.

Comment: Thanx! I love france!